# usage of glbufferdata in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, buffer, opengl-3, gpu

let's say that I have the vbo id stored in an int, and I want to resize that buffer; what would I do?
1st choice: use `glbufferdata` function after binding the buffer.
2nd choice:.use `gldeletebuffers` then regenerate the buffer and use `glbufferdata` function after binding the buffer.

So my question is does `glbufferdata` deallocate the buffer by it self or it didn't?

Answer (score 1):

Just call `glBufferData`. The `glDeleteBuffers` / `glGenBuffers` calls are unnecessary.

Think about it this way: `glBufferData` creates a new buffer.  The `glGenBuffers` function creates a new *name* (integer) for a bufffer.

You don't need to deallocate the buffer yourself… not that OpenGL gives you a way to do that. Your OpenGL implementation will do that for you after it is done using the data in the buffer, as long as you don't hold a reference to it.

Comment: so let's say that I have never called the function `glDeleteBuffers` at the end of the program, will OpenGL deallocate the resources for me?

Comment: Yes opengl driver will claim the memory on driver side and cleanup gpu memory.

Comment: Okay, but while I was writing OpenGL code I was debugging the code (Run the application) for each block I have written (I didn't deallocate buffers), but I have noticed my computer slow down a little bit after each run, how could you explain this? and why did OpenGL developers add such a function if it weren't uesd to clean up the memory?

Comment: "and why did OpenGL developers add such a function if it weren't uesd to clean up the memory?" Because the function is used for something else. Your OpenGL implementation will automatically clean up the memory, the `glDeleteBuffers` function removes a *reference* to a buffer.

Comment: Any opinion on `glBufferSubData` then? (I ask because of [this](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Data_Specification).)

Comment: glBufferSubData can force OpenGL to finish using any data in the buffer before the command can complete, *potentially* causing performance problems. As an optimization, glBufferData can complete while the data being replaced is still being used, by putting the new data in a different part of memory. If yo want double buffering, you basically get it for free with glBufferData and have to do it yourself if you use glBufferSubData.

Answer (score 1):

Is it legal OpenGL to re-allocate the storage of a buffer object with a different size? Yes. Is it a good idea? Well, consider this.

OpenGL has a new(ish) way to allocate storage for a buffer: `glBufferStorage`. It allocates "immutable" storage. So called because, once allocated, you *cannot* re-allocate it.

The people behind OpenGL would not have added this immutable buffer allocation method if they thought that reallocating the storage of a buffer object was a good idea.

Comment: Could you please explain why it is not a good idea? and consider if there some scenarios that I have to resize the buffer to add more data what is the best way to do that without cause a memory leak?

Comment: @O-BL: If the makers of something give you a second way to do a thing that doesn't have all of the features of the first way, that's a good indication that the features it lacks are probably bad ideas.